# IOS | Arranging buttons in multiple stack views

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I want to add four to five buttons dynamically in a UIView. My view must contain 2 buttons in a row and 2 or 3 rows based on the number of buttons. Which is the best way of doing this?. I don't want to use a collection view because of the overhead . I am thinking of adding multiple horizontal stack views in a vertical stack view. But I am stuck at the creation of stack views. The title for the buttons is provided by a service in Array. Please suggest me the best way of doing this.

PS: The image is representative only. The view I need should only have 4 to 5 buttons

[image: Sample UI needed]

Comment: use for loop and add stackview and buttons

Comment: How do I add buttons into horizontal stack view and  vertical stack view in the same for loop

Comment: You should give a try implementing this layout using UICollectionView.

Comment: One vertical stack view containing horizontal stack views... two for 4 buttons, 3 for 5 buttons. Give it a try... if you run into a problem, come back and post the actual code you are having trouble with.

Comment: `UICollectionView` for 4 or 5 cells, which will all be visible (i.e. no need to scroll) would be overkill and rather inefficient, and likely more difficult than other methods (such as stack views or simply setting relative constraints).

Answer (score 0):

Touching on the idea of using a loop, if you have your layout information in variables such as

```
let numberOfRows: Int
let buttonsPerRow: [Int]
```

Then when building your layout you could loop over them like:

```
let verticalStackView = UIStackView()
    //configure distribution, axis...

    for i in 0..<numberOfRows {
        let horizontalStackView = UIStackView()
        //configure distribution, axis...
        for _ in 0..<buttonsPerRow[i] {
            let b = UIButton()
            //configure button
            horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(b)
        }
        verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(horizontalStackView)
    }
```